I am struggling with the encoding of the states of DIP switches into a number
I am trying to understand the example code about Encoding the states of DIP switches into a number. I don't understand the code they use for encoding the binary into a number.
/*
 * This example code is in the public domain
 *
 * Tutorial page: https://arduinogetstarted.com/tutorials/arduino-dip-switch
 */

#define POSITION_NUM 4
#define ON LOW
#define OFF HIGH

// define the pins connected to the dip switch
const int SWITCH_PINS[] = { 2, 3, 4, 5 };

void setup() {
  // Initialize serial communication
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // Set the DIP switch pins as inputs with pull-up resistors enabled
  for (int i = 0; i < POSITION_NUM; i++)
    pinMode(SWITCH_PINS[i], INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop() {
  int encoded_state = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < POSITION_NUM; i++) {
    int state = digitalRead(SWITCH_PINS[i]);

    if (state == ON)                                // 
      encoded_state |= 1 << (POSITION_NUM - i - 1); // this is what I don't understand
  }
}

I hope you guys can give me an explanation for the part I've marked in the code.

What is it that you don't understand, specifically?  It looks like they are using the (nth) bit of encoded_state to represent the state of the (nth) pin, so bit #0 (aka the least-significant-bit) of encoded_state will be 1 if pin #0 is ON or 0 if pin #0 is off, and bit #1 will be 1 if pin #1 is ON or 0 if pin #1 is off, and so on.

Do you know what the << operator does? Do you know what |= does?
